# html5lib requires setuptools version 18.5 or above; please upgrade before installing (you have 0.6)

Tags: python, pip

When i try to give a pip install on my `requirements.txt` file, it fails as mentioned below:

```
html5lib requires setuptools version 18.5 or above; please upgrade before installing (you have 0.6)

Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-5xXCfM/html5lib/ .
```

I did go through some of the previous post on this where some user mentioned it got resolved by specifying :

```
pip install html5lib --upgrade
```

But when i issue the above command it tells me to update the setup tools, and when I try to update or upgrade `setuptools` it says already up to date.

Can someone suggest me what can be done in this case?

Answer (score 14):

It seems there's a [bug](https://github.com/html5lib/html5lib-python/issues/280) in older `html5lib` versions that didn't support old `setuptools` versions, this is fixed in newer `html5lib` versions.

So you can require a newer version of `html5lib` or if you can't mess with your dependencies just upgrade your `setuptools` with:

```
pip install -U setuptools
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you on a mac per chance? try adding the --user flag to your pip command

Comment: Hi @YFP i am using windows 7 and i am working on RHEL 6 server with python 2.6.6

Comment: @Jay Is your windows version out of date or the RHEL version?

Comment: <flamewar>Oh you poor thing...</flamewar>
How does easy_install behave?
easy_install --dry-run -U setuptools